# Checkbox value does not show in confirm popup javascript

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

I have made a email sending form , in which confirmation popup window show the preview the email information to user. In my code form text input show correctly, but no data show for checkbox in preview pop up window.I need to show checkbox data in confirm box.

Thanks to all

Here is my code

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
<script src="js/jquery_003.js"></script>

<script src="js/Mail.js"></script>



</head>
<body style="margin: 0px;">

            <div class="onedari_form_wrapper info_form_wrapper ajast_onedari_form mgt0">
                <form id="contactForm">
                    <div class="form_field">
                        <label id="name">Name<span class="red">*</span></label>

                        <input kl_virtual_keyboard_secure_input="on" placeholder="Name" class="custom_input" name="name" type="text" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_field">
                        <label id="mail">Email<span class="red">*</span></label>
                        <input kl_virtual_keyboard_secure_input="on"  class="custom_input" name="mail" type="text" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_field">
                        <label id="age">Age<span class="red">*</span></label><br>
                        <input kl_virtual_keyboard_secure_input="on" style="width: 30%" placeholder="" class="custom_input" name="age" type="text" required>
                    </div>
                    <p style="margin: 0px 0px 8px;"><label id="work">Work<span class="red">*</span></label></p>



                                            <div class="category-wrapper">


 <input  id="CategoryCategory10" class="checkbox" value="10" name="data[]" type="checkbox" >
 <label for="CategoryCategory10">App development</label>
  <br>                                          <input  id="CategoryCategory209" class="checkbox" value="209" name="data[]" type="checkbox"> <label for="CategoryCategory209">System management</label>
          <br>                           
                                            <input  id="CategoryCategory213" class="checkbox" value="213" name="data[]" type="checkbox"> <label for="CategoryCategory213">Web</label><br>
                                            <input id="CategoryCategory19" class="checkbox" value="19" name="data[]" type="checkbox"> <label for="CategoryCategory19">Graphics</label><br>




                <br>

                    <button id="send" class="submit bg_red" type="button" name="send">Submit</button>

                </form>
            </div>




</body>
</html>
```

Mail.js

```
$(function(){
    // sendForm
    $("#send").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        chackError("#contactForm");
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".layerOff", function(){
        $(".overlay").remove();
    });
});


function chackError(selector){
    var $form = $(selector);
    var name = $form.find("input[name='name']").val();
    var mail = $form.find("input[name='mail']").val();
    var age = $form.find("input[name='age']").val();
    /*var work = $form.find("textarea[name='work']").val();*/

    var dataval =  document.getElementsByName("data[]"); 
             // or document.querySelectorAll('[name="summer[]"]');

var checked = [].filter.call( dataval , function( v ){
    return v.checked;
});



    $form.find(".coution").remove();
    var error_frag = false;


    if ( checked.length < 1 ) {
  $("#work").append("<span class='coution'><br>Work field reqire</span>");
        error_frag = true;
        error_kind = "#work";       
}

    if(age == ""){
        $("#age").append("<span class='coution'><br>Age field reqire</span>");
        error_frag = true;
        error_kind = "#age";
    }
    if(mail == ""){
        $("#mail").append("<span class='coution'><br>email field reqire</span>");
        error_frag = true;
        error_kind = "#mail";
    }
    if(name == ""){
        $("#name").append("<span class='coution'><br>Name field reqire</span>");
        error_frag = true;
        error_kind = "#name";
    }
    if(error_frag === false){


         var theAnswer = confirm("Please confirm that the following Information is correct:\n  Name:" +name+"\nAge :"+age+"\nJob :"+checked ); //if the user presses the "OK" button display the message "Javascript is cool!!" 




    }

     if (theAnswer){sendForm(); }

    else{
        var targetY = $(error_kind).offset().top;
        var headerH = $("#header").height();
        var ajast = ($(window).width() >= 761)? 80 : 20;
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: targetY - headerH - ajast}, 'fast');
    }
}


function sendForm(){


    var post_data = $("#contactForm").serialize();
    $("#contactForm").find("input, checkbox, textarea").val("").end().find(":checked").prop("checked", false);
    $.post("sendMail.php",
        post_data,
        function(data){
            if(data.success === false){
                alert("error");
                $(".overlay").remove();
            }else{
                $("body").append("<div class='overlay'></div>");
                $(".overlay").html(data.message);
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 'fast');

            }
        },
        "json"
    );
    return false;
}
```

Comment: have you checked with some alert to see which level stop working?

Comment: I think var theAnswer need to edit

Comment: If I set alert box for checked variable i show this output: [object HTMLInputElement],[object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: i may be unclear... can you try and put an alert after var ajast ? to see if it goes there or if is blocked before that line?